# Why Android Studio does not show corresponding layout file in attributes panel of layout inspector?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, layout-inspector

I am trying to inspect layout for a fragment, and I want to open correct xml file which does contain the selected view.

When I google about it, I found that Android Studio allow us to do that if we are running our application on device > 29.

While I was trying it, I found that for some projects Android Studio does show the correct xml file in which the view is written. But, for other projects it does not show that information.

---

To clear it more, here are 2 screenshots of the different projects.

[image]

Here, Android studio only shows the `@id/buttonAddNew` for the button. But it does not show the xml file.

---

[image]

But, here Android Studio shows the `@id/imageViewNotificationBell` along with the `home_fragment.xml` file name and line number.

---

So, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you that the first layout was compiled with the current build tools? That's gonna be something that's handled by aapt, I would imagine, so if it was built with an old enough version, that information won't be there.

Comment: @MikeM. Both the layouts are build with the same android studio versions with same gradle versions. The dependencies version may be different for both.